# How to solve linear differential-difference equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, differential-operators

Given a linear differential-difference equation:
$$A_{n+2}+\partial A_{n+1}+\partial^2 A_n=0,$$
where $A$ is a function of $n$ and $x$, and $\partial$ represents the derivative about $x$.

How to solve this equation? The general case is this form
$$A_{n+2}+P_1 A_{n+1}+P_2 A_n=0,$$
where $P_1,P_2$ are differential operator depending on function of $x$.

I have tried to set $A_n=B^nA_0$, where $B$ is a pseudo differential operator and $A_0$ is a function of $x$, then I obtain
$$B^2+P_1B+P_2=0.$$
After solving $B$, we have the solution of $A_n$. I don't know whether this is correct and how to do next.

Comment: Try $A_n(x) = be^{rx}c^n$.  You can get a relationship between the constants $c$ and $r$.

Answer (score 2):

Given any infinitely differentiable functions $A_0(x), A_1(x)$, we can proceed to find $A_n(x)$ for all $n \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$.

Given $A_0(x)=f(x), A_1(x)=g(x)$, where $f, g$ are given infinitely differentiable functions,  a general solution is 
$$ A_n(x) = c_nf^{(n)}(x) + d_ng^{(n-1)}(x) \quad \forall n \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\} $$ 
where $f^{(n)}(x)$, $g^{(n)}(x)$ represent the $n$th derivative (and we use the convention $f^{(0)}= f$, $g^{(0)}=g$, $g^{(-1)}= 0$), and $c_n, d_n$ are solutions to the linear recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
c_{n+2} &=-c_{n+1} - c_n \quad \forall n \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\} \\
d_{n+2} &=-d_{n+1} - d_n \quad \forall n \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\} 
\end{align*}
with initial conditions $(c_0,c_1)=(1,0)$, $(d_0,d_1) = (0,1)$.

Comment: How is this solution obtained? Is there any method for solving this type of equations?

Comment: @LuisMendo : Starting with $A_0=f$ and $A_1=g$ you obtain $A_2=-f''-g'$ and $A_3, A_4$, and so on, will just be combinations of derivatives of $f$ and $g$. So I guess the general form $A_n=c_nf^n+d_ng^{n-1}$ and you can verify it works (and get the proper recursion on the $c_n, d_n$ values) by induction.

Comment: I see, thank you